# Ask a user to type two binary values and do bitwise XOR operator

Tags: c#

I'm new in C# and I can't figure out how to do this. So I must be able to type in console any values and do XOR operator for them and give the result as 154. I have tried many things and I'm not sure which one has been the best try. Anyways, I pasted some kind of a crappy code below to give you an idea what I want.

```
 public static void Main()
 {                          
    Console.WriteLine("give binary values 11001101 and 01010111:");
    byte a = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());
    byte b = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());
    byte result = (byte)(a ^ b);
    Console.WriteLine(result);        
 }
```

Comment: How would the computer discern "10" as decimal from "10" as binary? (See the answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the base when converting with `Convert.ToByte` method

Try this one:

```
public static void Main()
{                          
    Console.WriteLine("give binary values 11001101 and 01010111:");
    byte a = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine(), 2);
    byte b = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine(), 2);
    byte result = (byte)(a ^ b);
    Console.WriteLine(result);        
}
```

Here is the MSDN documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396